# Give Name of selected CostCenter Eg:

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
  CostCenterNo |  CostCenterName   | ParentCostCenterNo |     |     
 --------------|-------------------|--------------------|-----|----- 
           761 | Power Plant       | null               |     |     
           762 | Turbine           |                    | 761 |     
           763 | Coolent           |                    | 762 |     
           764 | Plant & Machinery | null               |     |     
           765 | Roller Machine    | 764                |     |     
           766 | Vehicle & Motors  | null               |     |     
           767 | Hywa              |                    |     | 766
```

```sql
declare @CostCenterNo int
select  @CostCenterNo = 763

with CostCen as(Select * from @table where CostCenterNo=@CostCenterNo
union all
select one.* from @Table as one 
inner join  CostCen cc  on one.ParentCostCenterNo= cc.CostCenterNo)
select * from Costcen where CostcenterNo = @CostcenterNo

Select funcCostCenter(767) then it will Give Output- Vehicle & Motors
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: my question is...Create Function which will give Top Level CostCenterName of Particular CostCenter
If No Top Level Costcenter then Give Name of selected CostCenter
Eg:
Select funcCostCenter(767) then it will Give Output- Vehicle & Motors

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want

```
with CostCen as(
  Select * 
  from costCenters 
  where CostCenterNo=@CostCenterNo
  union all
  select one.* 
  from costCenters as one 
  inner join CostCen cc on cc.ParentCostCenterNo = one.CostCenterNo
)
select * 
from Costcen 
where ParentCostCenterNo is null
```

***Edit***

Scalar function using the above query to get top-level `CostCenterName` for a given `CostCenterNo` from `costCenters` table:

```
create function funcCostCenter(@CostCenterNo int)
returns varchar(2000)
as
begin 
    declare @res varchar(2000);
    with CostCen as(
        select * 
        from costCenters 
        where CostCenterNo=@CostCenterNo
        union all
        select one.* 
        from costCenters as one 
        inner join CostCen cc on cc.ParentCostCenterNo = one.CostCenterNo
    )
    select @res = CostCenterName
    from Costcen 
    where ParentCostCenterNo is null;
    return @res;
end;
```